# Which version of Sql Server could first run this?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

The query is:

```
select * from sys.databases
```

which gets information about all the databases on the server.  I am aware that the query fails on Sql 2000 because the structure was different.  To get similar results one would need to run this query:

```
select * from master..sysdatabases
```

The question is, which was the first version of Sql Server for which a query to `sys.databases` would have succeeded?

Comment: Going directy to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178534(v=sql.90).aspx), it seems that it started with SQL server 2005

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQL Server 2005.  Source: [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178534(v=sql.90).aspx)